# Java XML parsing: taking inner XML using SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an XML file with SAX and at some point I need the inner XML of an element. E.g., for the following XML

```
<a name="abc">
  <b>def</b>
<a>
```

I need to get the inner XML for the element *a*, which would be

```
<b>def<b>
```

What's the easiest way to do that?

Thanks.

Ivan

Comment: Why not use xpath? SAX coding is somewhat painful for the situation you described

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of situation I suggest using 2 content handlers.  The first is responsible for finding the relevant part of the document, and the second for processing the content.  My answer to a similar question (see link below) demonstrates how to implement this approach:

- [Using SAX to parse common XML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405702/using-sax-to-parse-common-xml-elements/3409270#3409270)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Just one more question. How to read the "pure XML code" with SAX? Should I reconstruct it (`startElement` reads the name of the element, `characters` reads the text inside...), or is there a better way? I want the other handler to take all the XML inside the element and return it as result.

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what you want to do (could you provide more details?).  Ultimately SAX just offers you the events and you need to process them accordingly.  StAX is a similar API that you may find easy to work with as you can control when the events are fired (ultimately you get the same information).

Comment: I'm analyzing a WSLA document. I need to get the info from some important elements like `SLAParameter`, `ServiceLevelObjective` etc. Also, for some important elements (e.g., `metric`) i need to get both info about the element (i.e., attribute values) and the whole XML code of the element.