# HTTP request for XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to use Flurry Analytics for my program on Android and I'm having trouble getting the xml file itself from the server.

I'm getting close because in the Log Cat System.out tag I can get half of it for some reason and it says "XML Passing Exception = java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: ?xml version = 1.0 encoding="UTF-8" etc... until about half way through my xml code. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm sending an HTTP get with the header requesting to accept the application/xml and it's not working properly. Any help is appreciated!

```
try {

                //HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                //HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
                //String xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String URL = "http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/Event?apiAccessCode=????&apiKey=??????&startDate=2011-2-28&endDate=2011-3-1&eventName=Tip%20Calculated";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
        get.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        get.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        HttpResponse responsePost = client.execute(get);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePost.getEntity(); 
        if (resEntity != null) 

        {  
                    System.out.println("Not null!");

                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                    String responseXml = EntityUtils.toString(responsePost.getEntity());
                    Document doc = db.parse(responseXml);
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("eventMetrics");


                    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
                    {
                        Node node = nodeList.item(i);   

                        Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                        NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("day");

                        Element dayElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);

                        nameList = dayElement.getChildNodes();

                        countString = dayElement.getAttribute("totalCount");
                        System.out.println(countString);
                        count = Integer.parseInt(countString);
                        System.out.println(count);
                        count += count;

                    }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("XML Passing Exception = " + e);

                }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The parse method that takes a string is for a URL format.  You need to wrap the String in a StringReader before parsing it.  It is even better if you can grab the XML as an InputStream and parse that, something like:

```
String uri =
    "http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/Event?apiAccessCode=?????&apiKey=??????&startDate=2011-2-28&endDate=2011-3-1&eventName=Tip%20Calculated";

URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(xml);
```

Comment: Awesome! It's working, thank you so much I've been working on this all day! Now to sort out my reading through the xml...

Answer (score 0):

I used HttpURLConnection and this is a work code.

```
URL url = new URL("....");
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream outStream = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter outStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream, "UTF-8");
outStreamWriter.write(requestedXml);
outStreamWriter.flush();
outStreamWriter.close();
outStream.close();

System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseMessage());

InputStream xml = httpConnection.getInputStream();
```