# Convert http response to XML Document in Java

Tags: java, xml, http

Please, is there any way to convert response i get over the internet to the xml DOM Document? I know that response text is in xml format (server is sending xml-formatted responses).
I haven't worked with http communication in Java so i have no idea how to do it. After Googling for a while i found several examples but without luck.

If i use method describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162063/http-request-for-xml-file) my Document equals to null :\

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(link);
```

:)))