# Android: How to get or read XML from URL to String

Tags: java, android

how to read XML and then convert/transform it to variable String, I have try with Jsop library, but not success, with JSoup I get html format.

I want to read link in below to String:
http://bowingdown.wordpress.com/feed/

And then put it to String, I want to as below, example;

```
String data = "<rss xmlns:content=blablabla><channel>blablbabla</channel></rss>";
```

And i have read in here [HTTP request for XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162063/http-request-for-xml-file/5162372#5162372), but not success.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you want to store the XML in one single String? Thats kinda bad, in my opinion. String uses 2 bytes per character, and I guess that RSS feed will keep growing. What do you try to succeced here?

Comment: I want to parsing with XmlPullParser, but before parsing it must be read with Class StringReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xml parsing techniques such as `XmlPullParser` ,`SAX parser` or `DOM parser`.

XML Pull parser is the parser recommended in the developer's site of android [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html) is a tutorial for Pull parser .

Comment: @HaicalRams Feel free to accept the answer if thats what you are looking for