# How to fetch xml from url and write in text file with java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm doing a project using google map,using google map api i will get all location details. so using that "url" i will get xml that will want write into a file.how can i do it please help me.please ignore all mistake in the question

Comment: You read documentation, books, tutorials. Then you try something.

Comment: you can use jsoup. the simple example of parse xml is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9947639/9493617).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider taking a look at things like:

[http request for xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162063/http-request-for-xml-file)
And
[How to write to file](http://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file)