# SAX Using Multiple DefaultHandler Extensions

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

The issue I am having is I want to parse out 1 XML document using extensions of the SAX defaultHandler class. When using just one handler I can parse out XML and assign different tags to properties of an object (see domain and area). Once I have these in the domain and area object I want to add them to another object (GroupedFiles) which has a list of of domains and areas. The issue I am having is parsing out 1 document using 2 handlers. My theory, albeit not the best coding practice, is to parse out the document twice, run through it once using the domain handler, set the domains, then add to grouped files, then do the same for area. Here is the code,

```
GroupedFiles groupedFiles = new GroupedFiles();
ArrayList<Domain> domains = new ArrayList<Domain>();
ArrayList<Area> areas = new ArrayList<Area>();

//Create parser from factory
XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

//Creates an input stream from the file "someFile.xml"
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("someFile.xml"));
InputSource source = new InputSource(in);

//Create handler instances
DomainHandler domainHandler = new DomainHandler();
AreaHandler areaHandler = new AreaHandler();

//Parses out XML from a document using each handler, 
//adding it to an object with the correct properties then adds those
//to another object which features Lists of Domains, Areas, and Directories.
parser.setContentHandler(domainHandler);
parser.parse(source);
domains = domainHandler.getXML();
groupedFiles.setDomain(domains);

parser.setContentHandler(areaHandler);
parser.parse(source);
areas = areaHandler.getXML();
groupedFiles.setArea(areas);
```

However I am unable to, and it appears to hang up on the second `parser.parse(source)`. If I look at the groupedFiles after running the domain is populated but areas isn't. Any advice?

Comment: Why don't you just define one handler to do what you want it to do in the first place?

Comment: I would if what each handler (there are more than 2, but for now only keeping to 2) was doing wasn't so complicated. The way they are parsing out the overly complicated XML (generated by a computer) makes it almost impossible to use just one handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to make multiple passes, you can swap content handlers during the process of parsing. `XMLReader` has a `setContentHandler` method that you can call to pass in a new handler. For instance, you can set a new content handler if in `startElement` you recognize a tag that begins an area covered by a different handler, or if you're leaving the element in `endElement` and want to switch back to a previous content handler.

For examples see this [JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-08-2000/jw-0804-sax.html?page=7) or check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3409270/217324).

Comment: I was trying to avoid this because it involves rewriting my code but I do think this will be the most appropriate option. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: to get the current stuff working you might try making a new InputSource, i suspect reusing it as you're doing is the problem. In the long run swapping contenthandlers seems a lot better.